# Notification system in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am building a responsive website same as social networking
I have 4 tables `checkin` `friend` `post` `notification`

Here is structure of `notification` table

```
 Notification

 id 
 user_id
 activity_type   
 source_id  
 created_date   
 created_by     
 updated_date   
 updated_by
```

Where activity type is a string for example "friendrequest" if someone accepts friend request,"checkin" if someone checkin to some event and "post" if someone creates a post.

Now i store the data in `Notification` table whenever any of those action is triggered,but i am confused that how should i display the data in a list to logged in users.Data in the `notification` table will be like this

```
id  user_id activity_type source_id created_date  
5   1       friend        488       2015-10-13   
6   48      checkin       10        2015-10-13   
7   1       checkin       9         2015-10-13   
8   9       friend        7         2015-10-13   
9   1       checkin       27        2015-10-13   
10  48      post          18        2015-10-13  
11  9       checkin       8         2015-10-13
```

Like as per the `activity_type` the `source_id` will connect to either of `event`,`checking`or `post` table. So which query should i use to display notification correctly.

And how do i control the notification fetch,like any activity should only be displayed to the user's friends only.

I used this query but its not working properly

```
SELECT
    group_concat(`user_id`) as 'users',
    `activity_type`,
    `source_id` as 'post'
FROM
    `notification`
WHERE
    `source_id` IN ("488") 
GROUP BY
    `source_id`,
    `activity_type` 
ORDER BY
    `source_id`
```

Let me know if there are any example projects available online as well
From the answers i got here i wrote this query
Let me know if it can be improvise any other way

```
 SELECT 
      notification.*,event.title 
 FROM 
      notification 
 INNER JOIN 
      event 
 ON 
      event.id = notification.source_id 
 AND 
      notification.activity_type = "checkin"
 WHERE
      notification.user_id in (488,489) 
 UNION 
 SELECT 
      notification.*,user.firstname FROM notification 
 INNER JOIN 
      user 
 ON 
      user.id = notification.source_id 
 AND 
      notification.activity_type = "friend"
 WHERE
      notification.user_id in (488,489)
```

What should i do to find the friends of logged in user?
Should i write another query like

```
Select friend_id from friend where user_id=1
```

and save the array of `id` and pass it to the `notification` queries above

Is there any way to do that any other way without writing 2 different queries?

Comment: How will you know if the user's viewed the notification? Usually there's a column called `is_read` with a 0/1 so that you only fetch `WHERE is_read = 1`.. etc?

Comment: I would actually have a table that stores everybody who read the post.

Comment: @Darren actually i am not worried about if user has already read it or not and i do have separate table `notification_read` for that and i will insert data in that to track if its read or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since source_id field may link to one of 3 tables, you can either

1. Use left join to join these 3 tables on the notification table using source_id field. Based on activity_type you can decide which fields to display from the resultset in the application code. Drawback: if the same ids occur in all 3 tables, then the query will pull unnecessary data.
2. Create 3 queries for the 3 tables where you join each source table to the notification table based on the activity_type field and combine them in a union query to get a single resultset.
3. Depending on the content of the 3 source tables, you may choose to denormalise and include details of the events within the notification table, so you do not have to join to the source tables. For example, if sy becomes a friend of another, then you can explicitly store the friend's name in the notification table.

To display notifications to friends only is relatively easy, all notifications displayed should be originated by friends. You did not disclose the structure of the friend table, but I guess you have 2 fields that relate to the users table user_id field. So, using the friend table you inner join the notification table the way you did fdor the query that displays the friends of a user.

Comment: thank you for your replay and i am a little but clear not than before and i am confused between your 2nd and 3rd option of which is faster and better to use and will be faster??

Comment: You need to test both solutions and see which works for you better. Denormalised data structures are usually faster for a select query, however, there are tradeoffs in terms of storage space and maintaining data integrity.

Comment: ok thank you... Include link in your answer if there are any similar examples available online..

Comment: I have updated my question and included a query.. let me know about your thoughts on that and if it can be improvised in any way

Comment: Leave the AND notification.activity_type = "checkin" out of the query with the left joins. You implemented my 1st suggestion, so I sincerely hope that you do not have too many common ids through your source tables.

Comment: actually i do have common ids.. but i dont get the idea of your 2nd suggestion so can you please give me any example of that and i will implement it according to my tables

Comment: What are you not familiar with: simple selects or union?

Comment: ok.. i have updated the question.. I am using that last query in question but the problem is i am only getting `event.title` not `user.firstname`.. It returns null value for `user.firstname`. I have same datatype for both column `varchar(255)`

Comment: Have inner joins instead of left ones if you use union.

Comment: Perfect..!!! Thank you very much for your time.. I appreciate it.. GOD bless you man

Comment: I have one more question.. To display the notification to friends only do i have to make changes in this same query or another query? so i should use inner join with friends in same query right??

Comment: is it ok if i just get id of logged in user's friends and than pass it in this array.. i have updated the question... Or let me know if there is any other way through the same query... thank you